# how to setup custom error processing only for custom compile command in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using scons to build my c++ projects.
I'm using next script to correctly process scons's errors:

```
34;;; SCons builds into a 'build' subdir, but we want to find the errors
35;;; in the regular source dir.  So we remove build/XXX/YYY/{dbg,final}/ from the
36;;; filenames.
37(defun process-error-filename (filename)
38  (let ((case-fold-search t))
39    (setq f (replace-regexp-in-string
40             "[Ss]?[Bb]uild[\\/].*\\(final\\|dbg\\)[^\\/]*[\\/]" "" filename))
41    (cond ((file-exists-p f)
42           f)
43          (t filename))))
44
45(setq compilation-parse-errors-filename-function 'process-error-filename)
```

So. I want to use emacs not only with c++ and scons. But also with java and other languages.
How to setup emacs to use this "process-error-filename" function only when I'm running the

```
M-x compile   
scons
```

command?

Comment: I do not understand your question -- you mean, you want to make it interactive ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mode hooks
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html

```
(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()
  (set (make-local-variable
  'compilation-parse-errors-filename-function)
  'process-error-filename))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be a solution.